# Can't request permissions from Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm attempting to request certain permissions when I log in to Facebook using the Android SDK. Using the following code, the login is successful, but the permissions I wanted are neither granted nor declined. It appears they were not even requested. What's wrong?

```
    login_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_photos"));
    login_button.setFragment(this);

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(PicTag.callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Log.v(PicTag.TAG, "Facebook login success: " + loginResult.toString());
            Log.v(PicTag.TAG, AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().toString());
            Log.v(PicTag.TAG, loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions().toString());


            if (shareFrag!=null){
                shareFrag.shareContent();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.v(PicTag.TAG, "Facebook login canceled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.v(PicTag.TAG, "Facebook login error: " + exception.toString());
            if (shareFrag!=null){

                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you testing this with a user that has admin/dev/test roles for your app? Is your app's sandbox mode turned off? And finally, is your app approved for the user_photos permission?

Answer (score 0):

According to `"user_photos"` [Permissions documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-user_photos):

> If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it.

This is a new Facebook policy and you will most likely need to sumbit you application for [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit).